# ParallaxView doesn't work after April Update

Tags: c#, uwp, parallax

After the April Update of Windows 10 the parallax effect in ParallaxViev Control doesn't work. An example taken from microsoft docs:

```
<Grid>
        <ParallaxView Source="{x:Bind ForegroundElement}" VerticalShift="50">

            <!-- Background element -->
            <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="Assets/SplashScreen.scale-200.png"
               Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </ParallaxView>

        <!-- Foreground element -->
        <ListView x:Name="ForegroundElement">
            <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 5</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 6</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 7</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 8</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 9</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 10</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 11</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 13</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 14</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 15</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 16</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 17</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 18</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 19</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 20</x:String>
            <x:String>Item 21</x:String>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Are there any instructions how to restore it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this issue and reported it via the Feedback Hub at this [link](https://aka.ms/AA1etx4) was wondering if was only one but more people I ask the more they say they have the same problem, and they do, if you could add your comments to the Hub on that issue it should hopefully help get it resolved!

Edit:

Since reporting this issue there will be a fix delivered later in Summer 2018 to resolve this problem with the ParallaxView, was informed this would be the case from Microsoft

Update:

Windows 10 April 2018 Update has since been patched this month and should have resolved this problem with the Parallax View